# Convert Field Collections into Paragraphs during Migration

Tags: migrations, paragraphs, 8

I have a content type that uses Field Collections in Drupal 7. I am migrating to Drupal 8. Is there a way to convert the Field Collection Entity into Paragraph during migration?

Answer (score 0):

As more sites migrate from D7 to D8, this is definitely a needed functionality. I see that there is now a patch for Paragraphs that is attempting to address that: https://www.drupal.org/node/2911241

If you can test and/or contribute, we can get this moving along!